# Does an awk script or command execute itself to every line it reads?

Tags: linux, command-line, awk

I got an awk script named my_awk:

```
#!usr/bin/awk -f

{ 
if ($1 == "#START") { FS=":";} 
else if ($1 == "#STOP") { FS = " ";}
else { print $3} 
}
```

And I invoked it through:

```
cat my_file | awk -f my_awk
```

I'm new to awk so I'm ignorant about awk's mechanism.
Will this my_awk script execute its command to the whole my_file or to each line of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pipe something to a script, the script will only be executed once. So, for example if you do:

```
foo | bar
```

then `bar` is called only once, with its STDIN being whatever `foo` wrote to STDOUT.

You have a [useless use of `cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) there, since you could just do:

```
awk -f my_awk < my_file
```

Or, since `awk` can directly work with file name arguments:

```
awk -f my_awk my_file
```

If you go further, `awk` itself is a tool that works on line-by-line basis, but it's really called only once by the shell. From [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html):

> Like most UNIX utilities, AWK is line oriented. That is, the pattern specifies a test that is performed with each line read as input.

Comment: but how awk works of the file? The script I wrote above has successfully changed the FS separator for 2 different lines!

Comment: See my updated answer.